# Using multiple fonts types in console application with WinAPI

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console

I'm writting a console application using WinAPI and I noticed a strange behavior of `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx` function.

The app uses two types of fonts:

```
// small font
CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX font0;
font0.cbSize = sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX);
font0.nFont = 0;
font0.dwFontSize = { 8, 16 };
font0.FontFamily = FF_DONTCARE;
font0.FontWeight = FW_NORMAL;
wcscpy_s(font0.FaceName, L"Consolas");

// large font
CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX font1;
font1.cbSize = sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX);
font1.nFont = 1;
font1.dwFontSize = { 16, 32 };
font1.FontFamily = FF_DONTCARE;
font1.FontWeight = FW_BOLD;
wcscpy_s(font1.FaceName, L"Consolas");

SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(outHnd, FALSE, &font1)
printf("This text is big!\n");
        
SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(outHnd, FALSE, &font0);
printf("This text is small!\n");
```

After launching the application both text lines look the same (like `font0`). But if I add `Sleep(100)` between `printf("This text is big!\n")` and `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(outHnd, FALSE, &font0)`, the program will work correct (1st text is bigger than 2nd). It also works when I use delay loop:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 100000000)
   i++;
```

Why is this happening and how to change fonts without additional delay functions/loops?

Comment: What are the return values of the `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx` calls in the example?

Comment: @tambre They always return 1.

Comment: yes, this effect is present. can confirm

Comment: @dsony According to the docs, to obtain the font size for the `CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX` structure you should call `GetConsoleFontSize` please try that and see if it helps.

Comment: this is `conhost` synchronization bug

Comment: @tambre @RbMm Using `GetConsoleFontSize` doesn't help. Is there any other way to avoid this bug without any delay?

Comment: @dsony - no way. this bug or feature of conhost. I can describe this in all details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in general situation next - in console output involved two process - your application (*Client*) and `conhost.exe` (*Server*) (created by your process) (this is begin from vista, in `xp` - your app and + `csrss.exe`)

every console function including text output in your process make remote (synchronous) call to `conhost.exe` (via internal `ConsoleCallServer`). for understand why this behavior need debug `conhost.exe`

in current implementation `conhost.exe` have 3 threads:

1. `ConsoleIoThread` thread - it communicate with your console
   application
2. `ConsoleInputThread` this is UI thread for console, spin in
   `GetMessage` loop
3. `Microsoft::Console::Render::RenderThread::_ThreadProc` - this
   thread wait on some event (let name it `m_hEvent`). this event set by
   `ConsoleIoThread` when your app request some action, like text
   output or font change. perform this action and begin again wait on
   event (`m_hEvent`)

let look what is happens when you call `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx` on Server side:
`ConsoleIoThread` (1) awaken and do next:

```
SrvSetConsoleCurrentFont
  SCREEN_INFORMATION::UpdateFont(FontInfo*)
    SCREEN_INFORMATION::RefreshFontWithRender
      Microsoft::Console::Render::Renderer::TriggerFontChange(int, FontInfo*)
        Microsoft::Console::Render::GdiEngine::UpdateFont(FontInfo*)
        SetEvent(m_hEvent)
```

briefly: create/select to device context new font and notify render thread (3) by `SetEvent(m_hEvent)`

when you call `printf` on Server side again `ConsoleIoThread` (1) awaken and do next:

```
SrvWriteConsole 
  DoSrvWriteConsole
    WriteCharsLegacy
      Microsoft::Console::Render::Renderer::TriggerRedraw(SMALL_RECT*)
        Microsoft::Console::Render::GdiEngine::Invalidate(SMALL_RECT*)
        SetEvent(m_hEvent)
```

after this render thread (3) is awaken and render your text with current font.

what is be if you do next calls *too fast* ?:

```
SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(outHnd, FALSE, &font1)
printf("This text is big!\n");
SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(outHnd, FALSE, &font0);
printf("This text is small!\n");
```

the `ConsoleIoThread` (1) call `UpdateFont(FontInfo*)` **two time before** `RenderThread` (3) is awaken ! as result second call to `UpdateFont(FontInfo*)`  overwrite first call.

but if you do next:

```
SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(outHnd, FALSE, &font1)
printf("This text is big!\n");
Sleep(1000);// or any unknown delay
SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(outHnd, FALSE, &font0);
printf("This text is small!\n");
```

`RenderThread` (3) **is awaken first time when you wait in** `Sleep` and do render with `font1` and then already render with `font0`

Comment: And... What's the solution? Just wait an arbitrary amount of time and hope it's not too fast? This seems like a *very* bad hack.

Comment: @tambre - I not view good solution. here I only describe what/why is happens

Comment: Not really an answer is it then? Not sure why it's accepted as an answer even if it doesn't even propose a solution to the question, just why the problem happens in the first place.

Comment: @tambre - what if this is windows bug ? i explain why this and that no 100% correct solution, if you want at once print with two or more fonts. if you have better solution/answer - post it